# Return value when members of one array are in another

Tags: excel

In Excel I am trying to return a name from a table in a second table when the **Team Name** matches. So if values from both arrays exist put the persons name next to each match of that item.

So in column Coach in this table.

```
Team    Member  Coach
Team C  Aida    NA
Team F  Alana   
Team A  Anne    
Team B  Arun    
Team F  Bellinda    
Team C  Bill    
Team A  Charlie 
Team F  Daphne  
Team E  Eliza   
Team B  Esther  
Team D  Harry   
Team D  Lacy    
Team C  Lauren  
Team D  Laurie  
Team B  Mohammad    
Team E  Morgan  
Team F  Peter   
Team A  Sally   
Team A  Sammy   
Team C  Stephen 
Team E  Tiffany 
Team D  Tim 
Team A  Tom 
Team E  Tracy   
Team F  Wally
```

Return the coach that matches with the team from this list.

```
Teams Coach Coaches
Team A  Sarah
Team E  Sarah
Team F  Brett
Team B  Brett
Team C  Nathan
Team D  Theresa
```

So the first entry would be

```
Team    Member  Coach
Team C  Aida    Nathan
```

I have tried a variation of index match and if formula's and I just can't figure it. This is my last attempt.

```
=IF(ISNA(MATCH(E2:E7,A2:A26,0)),F2:F7,"NA")
```

Comment: It seems that a simple `VLookup` of the coach from the team name is all that you want, with the member playing no role. Perhaps I am missing something.

Comment: @John Coleman    i tried that but couldn't get it to work.

Comment: Actually just realized that the original sheet at work i didnt create that helper column Coaches with the Teams beside them.